# Factor Columns converting to numbers in R DataFrame after mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, tidyverse, kaggle

My R code was working perfectly fine in R Studio but when I pasted same code in Kaggle Notebook it started giving errors. It converted my factors to numbers when applied if-else with mutate. Has anyone else ever experienced this problem?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution, but can you try using `if_else` instead of ifelse?

Answer (score 0):

`as.character` Did the Job. I hope this helps someone who encounters similar problem in future.

```
kaggle = kaggle %>%
  mutate(
      prog_experience = if_else(prog_experience == "", "I have never written code", as.character(prog_experience))
      )
```